# Sync branch with master in git.

Tags: git

I have a branch with couple of commits, I want to sync it with the master branch.
I am trying to rebase it interactively and I am picking all the commits.

```
git rebase -i master
```

In this case I have to manually resolve all the conflicts for each commit, is there a way to avoid that and resolve the conflicts only for the last commit.

Comment: You could merge instead of rebasing: `git merge master`.  This does something different than rebasing, but it seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first squash all commits and then do the rebase.

```
git merge-base <my_branch> master
```

Result is the hash of the best common ancestor between your branch and master

```
git rebase -i <hash>
```

Squash all your commits to a single commit

```
git rebase -i master
```

Now you should see only a single commit there, and you can solve the conflicts once.